# Maxwell's Relations and Differentiating With Respect to Nᵢ

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

I was wondering if anyone could write out Maxwell's relations for partial derivatives with respect to particle count $N_i$. Starting from the fundamental thermodynamic relation,

\begin{align}
  \mathrm{d}U(S, V, N_i) &= 
    T\mathrm{d}S - P\mathrm{d}V + \sum_{i}\mu _i\mathrm{d}N_i\\
  \mathrm{d}U(S, V, N_i) &=
    \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}
      \right)_{V, \{N_i\}}\mathrm{d}S
    + \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}
      \right)_{S, \{N_i\}}\mathrm{d}V
    + \sum_{i}\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial N_i}
      \right)_{S, V, \{ N_{j\neq i}\}}\mathrm{d}N_i
\end{align}

I tried to write a relation by differentiating with respect to particle number, but I want to make sure all of my subscripts are correct. I wrote, for a first Maxwell relation,

$$
  \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial N_i}
    \right)_{S, V, \{N_{j\neq i}\}} = 
  \left(\frac{\partial \mu _i}{\partial S}
    \right)_{V, \{N_{j\neq i}\}} = 
  \left(\frac{\partial ^2U}{\partial N_i \partial S} 
    \right)_{V, \{N_{j\neq i}\}}
$$

Are these subscripts correct? I just want to make sure this is accurate. If someone could write out the remaining Maxwell relations, that would be great. There should be seven more relations left.

Comment: It seems to me what you did is correct.

Comment: @ChetMiller Should the middle partial derivative have all $N_i$ held constant or just $N_{j\neq i}$?

Comment: You're right.  I missed that.  It should be all of them.

Comment: @CalebWilliamsUC, if you got your answer, feel free to self answer it. Self answer are always appreciated and it also help future readers.

Comment: @NilayGhosh Alright! I will self-answer a bit later.

Answer (score 1):

Just now getting back around to this.

\begin{align}
  \mathrm{d}U(S, V, 
\left \{ N_i \right \}) &= 
    T\mathrm{d}S - P\mathrm{d}V + \sum_{i}\mu _i\mathrm{d}N_i\\
  \mathrm{d}U(S, V, 
\left \{ N_i \right \}) &=
    \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}
      \right)_{V, \{N_i\}}\mathrm{d}S
    + \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}
      \right)_{S, \{N_i\}}\mathrm{d}V
    + \sum_{i}\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial N_i}
      \right)_{S, V, \{ N_{j\neq i}\}}\mathrm{d}N_i
\end{align}
$$
  \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}
    \right)_{S, \{N_{i}\}} = 
  -\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial S}
    \right)_{V, \{N_{i}\}} = 
  \left(\frac{\partial ^2U}{\partial S \partial V} 
    \right)_{ \{N_{ i}\}}
$$

$$
  \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial N_i}
    \right)_{S, V, \{N_{j\neq i}\}} = 
  \left(\frac{\partial \mu _i}{\partial S}
    \right)_{V, \{N_{j}\}} = 
  \left(\frac{\partial ^2U}{\partial N_i \partial S} 
    \right)_{V, \{N_{j\neq i}\}}
$$
$$
  -\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial N_i}
    \right)_{S, V, \{N_{j\neq i}\}} = 
  \left(\frac{\partial \mu _i}{\partial V}
    \right)_{S, \{N_{i}\}} = 
  \left(\frac{\partial ^2U}{\partial N_i \partial V} 
    \right)_{S, \{N_{j\neq i}\}}
$$

\begin{align}
  \mathrm{d}H(S, P,
\left \{ N_i \right \}) &= 
    T\mathrm{d}S + V\mathrm{d}P + \sum_{i}\mu _i\mathrm{d}N_i\\
  \mathrm{d}H(S, P, 
\left \{ N_i \right \}) &=
    \left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial S}
      \right)_{P, \{N_i\}}\mathrm{d}S
    + \left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial P}
      \right)_{S, \{N_i\}}\mathrm{d}P
    + \sum_{i}\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial N_i}
      \right)_{S, P, \{ N_{j\neq i}\}}\mathrm{d}N_i
\end{align}
$$
  \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial P}
    \right)_{S, \{N_{i}\}} = 
  -\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}
    \right)_{P, \{N_{i}\}} = 
  \left(\frac{\partial ^2H}{\partial P \partial S} 
    \right)_{ \{N_{ i}\}}
$$

$$
  \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial N_i}
    \right)_{S, P, \{N_{j\neq i}\}} = 
  \left(\frac{\partial \mu _i}{\partial S}
    \right)_{P, \{N_{i}\}} = 
  \left(\frac{\partial ^2H}{\partial N_i \partial S} 
    \right)_{P, \{N_{j\neq i}\}}
$$
$$
  \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial N_i}
    \right)_{S, P, \{N_{j\neq i}\}} = 
  \left(\frac{\partial \mu _i}{\partial P}
    \right)_{S, \{N_{i}\}} = 
  \left(\frac{\partial ^2H}{\partial N_i \partial P} 
    \right)_{S, \{N_{j\neq i}\}}
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathrm{d}F(T, V, 
\left \{ N_i \right \}) &= 
    -S\mathrm{d}T - P\mathrm{d}V + \sum_{i}\mu _i\mathrm{d}N_i\\
  \mathrm{d}F(T, V, 
\left \{ N_i \right \}) &=
    \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}
      \right)_{V, \{N_i\}}\mathrm{d}T
    + \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial V}
      \right)_{T, \{N_i\}}\mathrm{d}V
    + \sum_{i}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial N_i}
      \right)_{T, V, \{ N_{j\neq i}\}}\mathrm{d}N_i
\end{align}
$$
  \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}
    \right)_{T, \{N_{i}\}} = 
  -\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}
    \right)_{V, \{N_{i}\}} = 
  \left(\frac{\partial ^2F}{\partial V \partial T} 
    \right)_{ \{N_{ i}\}}
$$

$$
  -\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial N_i}
    \right)_{T, V, \{N_{j\neq i}\}} = 
  \left(\frac{\partial \mu _i}{\partial T}
    \right)_{V, \{N_{i}\}} = 
  \left(\frac{\partial ^2F}{\partial N_i \partial T} 
    \right)_{V, \{N_{j\neq i}\}}
$$
$$
  -\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial N_i}
    \right)_{T, V, \{N_{j\neq i}\}} = 
  \left(\frac{\partial \mu _i}{\partial V}
    \right)_{T, \{N_{i}\}} = 
  \left(\frac{\partial ^2F}{\partial N_i \partial V} 
    \right)_{T, \{N_{j\neq i}\}}
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathrm{d}G(T, P, 
\left \{ N_i \right \}) &= 
    -S\mathrm{d}T + V\mathrm{d}P + \sum_{i}\mu _i\mathrm{d}N_i\\
  \mathrm{d}G(T, P, 
\left \{ N_i \right \}) &=
    \left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial T}
      \right)_{P, \{N_i\}}\mathrm{d}T
    + \left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial P}
      \right)_{T, \{N_i\}}\mathrm{d}P
    + \sum_{i}\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial N_i}
      \right)_{T, P, \{ N_{j\neq i}\}}\mathrm{d}N_i
\end{align}
$$
  -\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}
    \right)_{T, \{N_{i}\}} = 
  \left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}
    \right)_{P, \{N_{i}\}} = 
  \left(\frac{\partial ^2G}{\partial T \partial P} 
    \right)_{ \{N_{ i}\}}
$$

$$
  -\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial N_i}
    \right)_{T, P, \{N_{j\neq i}\}} = 
  \left(\frac{\partial \mu _i}{\partial T}
    \right)_{P, \{N_{i}\}} = 
  \left(\frac{\partial ^2G}{\partial N_i \partial T} 
    \right)_{P, \{N_{j\neq i}\}}
$$
$$
  \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial N_i}
    \right)_{T, P, \{N_{j\neq i}\}} = 
  \left(\frac{\partial \mu _i}{\partial P}
    \right)_{T, \{N_{i}\}} = 
  \left(\frac{\partial ^2G}{\partial N_i \partial P} 
    \right)_{T, \{N_{j\neq i}\}}
$$